# Any way to search just for the package name from npm search?

Tags: regex, node.js, npm

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've checked the [docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-search.html) but is there no way to just search for the package name from npm search?

Right now I'm getting all the package that has the word with the search-term on it.

e.g. `npm search express` brings up all the package with `express` on their description and name.. even with the regular expression. `npm search /^express$`

Do I have to install another npm package for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npm search --no-description <search_term>`.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct now even though @user3621841's was marked correct before. Looks like this got added in this [PR](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/13746).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code here](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/v1.3.21/lib/search.js#L98) for v1.3.21 the search via `npm search` is just done on each of the individual words in a list built from the following:

- description
- maintainers
- url
- keywords

Comment: Yeah. I just wish there was a way to just search for the package name instead of having to list all the packages that has the search-term on the above list.

Comment: I would suggest opening an [Issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues) highlighting the problem or even submitting a pull request.